# Grails Controller - Could not catch a SocketException

Tags: grails, exception, grails-2.0

When I try to catch an Exception in a controller method I could not catch SocketException. The controller action looks like:

```
def updateDeviceStartV1() {
      try {
         ...
         response.status = 200;
         response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
         response.outputStream << responseService.encryptedResponse // byte[]
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         log.error "Server faced unexpected exception", e
         response.status = 500;
         ...
      }
```

The SocketException is thrown by line "response.outputStream << responseService.encryptedResponse" because the client unexpectedly close the connection. Nevertheless, this exception is not catched and the console receives standard exception display...

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that if the method where the exception is raised doesn't throw the exception explicitly (with a throws in the signature), it will be thrown as an **UndeclaredThrowableException**. Then the type in your catch just doesn't match it. Try catching SocketException instead. Or if you can just catch them all using `catch(all)`.
Oh, take a look at [this](http://jts-blog.com/?p=9491).

Comment: However, your answer gave me deeper understanding of Groovy exception magic:-) Thanks

Comment: I'm glad =). But `catch(all)` should definitely catch any exception that was thrown from a deeper layer. What happens if you print the exception's class inside your catch block?